# inputting a line of numbers in hex

Tags: input, binary, bit-manipulation, hex

I have an two lines of binary numbers in hex to be input and then bit operations to be done on the lines. I did this:-

```
int main()
{

  vector < char > v1;
  vector < char > v2;
  char c;
  int i = 0;
  int j = 0;
  while((c = cin.get()) != ' ' || c!= '\0' || c!= '\n')
  {
    cin.putback(c);
    cin >> hex >> c;
    v1.push_back(0);
    v1[i] = v1[i] | c;
    i++;
  }

  while((c = cin.get()) != ' ' || c!= '\0' || c!= '\n')
  {
    cin.putback(c);
    cin >> hex >> c;
    v2.push_back(0);
    v2[j] = v1[j] | c;
    j++;
  }

  for(int i = 0; i < v1.size(); i++)
  cout << hex << v1[i]; //this I wrote to check whether I was doing the right thing

  return 0;
}
```

And I gave as input:-

```
eaa8b5f8aaf9174145bf43e1784b
bafa3ed18510abd11f4564e32133
```

But, when I compiled there was no output and as I was using an online compiler, it said time limit exceeded which I think is an indication for segfault.

Edit: I think my problem will be solved if I use a data type which acts as integer but is of 1 byte

Comment: You seem to be calling `cin.get()` three times every run through either loop. I doubt you are trying to read three characters. Try calling `cin.get()` outside of the while loop instead.

Comment: @AndresRiofrio...tried doing that....I replaced the other two cin.get() by just c...same result